# Is their a plan to support facial recognition persisted logins in codenameone libs

Tags: codenameone

Netbeans 12.3
Windows 10 Pro
Lates Simulator

Looking to see if codenameone will support facial recognition logins supported in IOS 14+

Regards

Comment: You mean something beyond the face id we support here? https://github.com/codenameone/FingerprintScanner

Comment: Thanks, It did not ocurr to me that the Fingerprint class contained Fingerprint.isFaceIDAvailable() method which does work. Thanks for your help. Regards